# getElementbyId does not work and returns null

Tags: javascript, html

When accessing the site, the image and characters are displayed for a moment with JavaScript,
It takes a lot of time to load the image, and we have to lengthen the fade-out time.

Once you visit the site, the cache will remain, so when you visit it again, the image will be displayed immediately and you will feel that 3 seconds is longer.

Therefore, I am trying to set it so that it can fade out after the image has been read.

When I run the test code below, `document.getElementById('firstimgs');` is null and no log is output.
When I changed it to `querySelectorAll("img");`, the code worked, but I can't do what I want to do this time because all the images are targeted.

Do you know what caused it?

```php
<div class="first-img">
    <p><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/imgs/top/first-banner.jpg" alt="r" id="firstimgs"></p>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

```
 function firstimg(){

  $('.first-img p').fadeIn(500);
      $('.first-img span').fadeIn(500);
    };
    setTimeout(firstimg, 10);
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var img_elements = document.getElementById('firstimgs');
        for (var i = 0; i < img_elements.length; i++) {
            img_elements[i].addEventListener('load', (e) => {
                console.log(" load");
            });
            img_elements[i].src = img_elements[i].getAttribute("src");
        }
      });
```

Comment: It makes no sense to iterate over a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById()
```

return single element

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```js
function firstimg() {
  $('.first-img p').fadeIn(500);
  $('.first-img span').fadeIn(500);
};

setTimeout(firstimg, 10);

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var img_elements = document.getElementById('firstimgs');
  img_elements.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    console.log(" load");
  });

  img_elements.src = img_elements.getAttribute("src");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced this issue. In my case, the function was misspelled.
It does matter, if the name of a function starts with a capital letter.
Or if all the letters are the same, like in the name of the prototype.
If you use an editor with automatic language completion, can be easier.
Like should be Code, which could support more programming languages.

But it is not so sure, that the error it is because of getElementById.
You just see, getElementById doesn't work and this seems to be a cause.
This is just the effect we can see, the error could be found elsewhere.
And the script stops at the first encountered error without a warning.

Just see what you had changed last time, look at each line of code.
Sometimes it is not so obvious, why a certain kind of error appears.
If nothing could work, you can also use a try / catch error checking.

With kind regards, Adrian Brinas

Answer (score -2):

1. Missing error:
   I found that the **id** in your **document.getElementById('firstimg')** is not the same as the id of the element. It is missing the '**s**' character.
2. Suggestion:
   If you are looking to get an array then use class instead of id, and to get elements by class use **getElementsByClassName('firstimgs')** instead **getElementById('firstimg')**. Because id is used for an element if it is the same, get the first element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried the idea I received, but the result did not change (I changed the id to class).